# JS AJAX sending multiple data array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am trying to send multiple data arrays in my ajax save function.

I can do each array individually like `data:hardwarePayload` and it will work. If I do `{hardware: hardwarePayload, service:servicePayload}` I get very weird JSON output. that looks like:

> hardware=%5B%7B%22hardwareName%22%3A%221%22%2C%22hardwareQuantity%22%3A%22%22%2C%22hardwareBYOD%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D&service=%5B%7B%22serviceName%22%3A%223%22%2C%22serviceQuantity%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D

I really need two arrays one hardware and one service so I can grab each one individually.

My code looks like this..

> ```
> self.save = function (form) {
>     var hardwareModel = [];
>     var serviceModel = [];
>     ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.services(), function (service) {
>         serviceModel.push(ko.toJS(service));
>     });
>     ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.hardwares(), function (hardware) {
>         hardwareModel.push(ko.toJS(hardware));
>     }); 
>   //allModel.push({accountId: ko.toJS(account)});
>     var hardwarePayload = JSON.stringify(hardwareModel);
>     var servicePayload = JSON.stringify(serviceModel);
>   //alert(JSON.stringify(serviceModel) +JSON.stringify(allModel));
>     $.ajax({
>         url: '/orders/add',
>         type: 'post',
>         data: {hardware: hardwarePayload, service:servicePayload}, //            data:hardwarePayload,
>         contentType: 'application/json',
>         success: function (result) {
>             alert(result);
>         }
>     });
> };
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**You should try this**

```
var hardwarePayload = hardwareModel;
var servicePayload = serviceModel;

var postData = {'hardware': hardwarePayload, 'service':servicePayload};

var postData = JSON.stringify(postData);

alert(postData);

$.ajax({
    url: '/orders/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: postData,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off if you do NOT *stringify* your *data*:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/orders/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: {hardware: hardwareModel, service:serviceModel}, //            data:hardwarePayload,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

(Note that I'm using the **not** stringified *hardwareModel* and *serviceModel*)

This way you can have jQuery handle the (json) data for the request.